# SinchPSTNsample Using javascript Shows Warning After running index.html file

Tags: sinch

i saw below warnning when running the sample html in chrome
Warning! Protocol "file" used to load page in Chrome.

Please avoid loading files directly from disk when developing WebRTC applications using Chrome.
Chrome disables access to microphone which prevents proper functionality.

You can allow working with "file:", if you start Chrome with the flag --allow-file-access-from-files

Please help me to get out of this

thank you

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which Operating System.

In OS X you can start Chrome by using:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```

While in Windows you'd start Chrome in the command prompt using:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Please note that the warning does not disappear in the sample app, this is the expected behaviour but now calls will work. In a production environment you should not even include this warning, since it's only meant as a friendly reminder for developers using local file storage (directly opening the .html file from disk).